# Getting the last second of the Day

Tags: php, time, timestamp, timing

In PHP 5.2, how to get the last second in a day? time() + 86400 gets the next Day only?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo date('r', strtotime('tomorrow') - 1);

returns 'Mon, 18 Jan 2010 23:59:59'
```

you need that deal with leap seconds (times such as `23:59:60`)

Comment: Leap second has no relevance here. For example, "2008-12-31 23:59:60" is the same as "2009-01-01 00:00:00". Quoting http://unix-time.com/ : "The Unix time number increases by exactly 86400 each day, regardless of how long the day is." and "When a leap second is inserted...the Unix time number increases continuously during the leap second...and then jumps down by 1 at the end of the leap second, which is the start of the next day."

Comment: GZipp, so you mean that my solution is also correct? :D Nice to learn about leap seconds though, I didn't know them earlier.

Answer (score 12):

```
strtotime('23:59:59');
```